# pandas Average If

Tags: python, pandas

In Excel there is a handy function called AVERAGEIF(). Is there any way to do something similar with pandas? For example, in the following table I would like to get a series of the average XS for Rank > 50.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Desired result:

[image]

My code:

```
df[df[['Rank A', 'Rank B', 'Rank C']] > 50].loc[:, 'XS'].mean(axis=0)
```

Outputs:

```
nan
```

Note: There are a lot of questions addressing average of grouped aggregates, but I have not found any addressing this specific problem.

Note also, that I simplified the question for clarity. The tables that I am working with are 300K rows x 110 columns, and they are being calculated in 100x in a loop. Some optimization is called for. For example, vector math tends to be much faster than a map function which operates on each cell separately.

Comment: Well presumably the XS column is a String. The word "7%" which is why you can't calculate the average of the words "7%", "1%", "7%" and "2%.

Comment: I removed the % sign from the images for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

We can create a mask for the DataFrame based on the condition, then use this indicator DataFrame as a filter and [multiply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) this by the XS column. This will create either the XS or `NaN` values based on the mask location. We can then take the [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html):

```
m = (df[['Rank A', 'Rank B', 'Rank C']] > 50)
res = m[m].mul(df['XS'], axis=0).mean(axis=0)
```

`res`:

```
Rank A    0.04
Rank B    0.01
Rank C    0.07
dtype: float64
```

We can add [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose [`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
res.to_frame(name='Average XS when rank > 50').T

                           Rank A  Rank B  Rank C
Average XS when rank > 50    0.04    0.01    0.07
```

---

`m`:

```
   Rank A  Rank B  Rank C
0    True   False   False
1    True    True   False
2   False   False    True
3   False   False   False
```

`m[m]`:

```
  Rank A Rank B Rank C
0   True    NaN    NaN
1   True   True    NaN
2    NaN    NaN   True
3    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Then [mulitply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) the new Series with the DataFrame on `axis=0`.  `True` will be handled as 1 and `NaN` will produce `NaN`.

```
res = m[m].mul(df['XS'], axis=0).mean(axis=0)

  Rank A Rank B Rank C
0   0.07    NaN    NaN
1   0.01   0.01    NaN
2    NaN    NaN   0.07
3    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Now [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) will work as expected since it will not consider `NaN` values when calculating the column average.

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Rank A': [82, 68, 42, 46],
    'Rank B': [36, 85, 24, 28],
    'Rank C': [36, 42, 72, 30],
    'XS': [0.07, 0.01, 0.07, 0.02]
})
```

Comment: No. Clip is also a good approach! I’ve also voted as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

```
>>> df[['Rank A', 'Rank B', 'Rank C']].mask(lambda x: x <= 50).clip(0, 1) \
                                      .mul(df[['XS']].values).mean()

Rank A    4.0
Rank B    1.0
Rank C    7.0
dtype: float64
```

If your column `XS` contains strings:

```
>>> df[['Rank A', 'Rank B', 'Rank C']] \
        .mask(lambda x: x <= 50).clip(0, 1) \
        .mul(df['XS'].str.strip('%').astype(float).to_frame().values).mean()

Rank A    4.0
Rank B    1.0
Rank C    7.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Rank A'] = df.where(df['Rank A'] > 50)['XS'].mean()
df['Rank B'] = df.where(df['Rank B'] > 50)['XS'].mean()
df['Rank C'] = df.where(df['Rank C'] > 50)['XS'].mean()
df.drop('XS', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
print(df)
```

output:

```
   Rank A  Rank B  Rank C
0    0.04    0.01    0.07
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fastest solution so far:

```
ranks = ['Rank A', 'Rank B', 'Rank C']
condition = df[ranks] < 50

out = df[ranks].mask(condition)               # Replace no good with NaN.
out = out.where(condition, df['xs'], axis=0)  # Replace good with xs values. 
means = out.mean(axis=0)                      # Get the mean for each column.
```

Fill the factor columns with xs values (if the ondition is True) or NaN's (if False).

Note: [`DataFrame.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) replaces all values where condition is True.
[`DataFrame.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) replaces all values where the condition is False.

On my benchmarks, this code was > 2x as fast as [Henry Eckers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70025164/2529619) answer which multiplies the mask by 'xs', and > 10x faster than [Wilian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70025328/2529619)'s answer which operates on each column separately.